# Selenium FirefoxDriver how to execute automated tests with Crontab

Tags: java, selenium, cron

I have a Debian built server and i need to run automated tests via crontab or anything else that fulfils the daily job.

I use Selenium WebDriver 2.45.0 Java Libraries.

With command line i can execute the script with :

```
 export DISPLAY=:0; 
 xvfb-run --auto-servernum --server-num=0 nohup java -jar test.jar;
```

But when i add the code to the Crontab like

`export DISPLAY=:0 && xvfb-run --auto-servernum --server-num=0 nohup java -jar test.jar;`
 
it just doesn't work. I also tried putting the code into a script like test.sh. it worked again with the command line but did not work with crontab.

I'm stuck.

Comment: Add absolute paths for everything, including java, and the location of the jar. That usually seems to be what messes me up with cron.

Comment: I have a very similar issues with the Firefox python webdriver. While I still see an empty window instance of Firefox appear at the run of the cron job the script appears to not be do any thing more than opening the window or produce any logged output. The script runs under the users local crontab using full paths and executes perfectly when run from the command line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After I add the following line to the top of the crontab screen, the problem has solved.
I don't know the technical answer but It just worked for me.

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a script from `/etc/crontab`, you need to ensure that the file is owned by `root` and is not world writable.

```
chown root:root /path/to/script; chmod o-w /path/to/script;
```

The cron files (`/etc/crontab` and `/etc/cron.d/*`) are treated differently than a normal user's `crontab`. Cron does this to protect from unintentional privilege escalation.

Also, make sure the file is properly formatted `cron` file:

```
# Example of job definition:
.---------------- minute (0 - 59)
|  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
|  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
|  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
|  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
|  |  |  |  |
*  *  *  *  * user-name  command to be executed
```

I also remember reading somewhere that there is an issue with Ubuntu ignoring files in `/etc/cron.d/*` that have dots in the filename, but I don't remember if it was all Debian variants or just Ubuntu-specific. So, you might want to check that too.